# Eclipse JDT API documentation, preferrably CHM format

Tags: eclipse, download, eclipse-jdt, chm

I am going to need to do some development with Eclipse JDT while on holiday. I will be off-line for the most of the time and therefore I will not be able to access the <strike>[Eclipse JDT API documentation]</strike> (edit : link is now dead) on the Web. I can't find a link to download the documentation in ZIP or PDF or, best of all, CHM format. Does anyone have a copy? Could you please provide a download link to it?

Do you think I should use HTTRack to simply mirror the above-mentioned website? I would really rather not. CHM is rather convenient for exploring any kind of API documentation. Anyone differs in opinion?

Comment: The current link in question is dead (points to an ad page)

Comment: feel free to delete it. looks like i can't @Pac0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download and unpack this one http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/doc/isv/3.2.1-r321_v20060907/isv-3.2.1-r321_v20060907.jar

Comment: Hi, do you know where can I download the latest version? In particular JDT 4.5.0.Thanks very much!